# How to access UDP Server using external IP Address

Tags: c#, .net, udp, server

I have the following UDP server listening on Port 11000:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace UDPServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static byte[] dataToSend = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    // get the ip and port number where the client will be listening on
    static IPEndPoint GetClientInfo()
    {
        // wait for client to send data
        using (UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(11000))
        {
            IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000);
            byte[] receive_byte_array = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);

            return groupEP;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var info = GetClientInfo(); // get client info

        /* NOW THAT WE HAVE THE INFO FROM THE CLIENT WE ARE GONG TO SEND
           DATA TO IT FROM SCRATCH!. NOTE THE CLIENT IS BEHIND A NAT AND
           WE WILL STILL BE ABLE TO SEND PACKAGES TO IT
        */

        // create a new client. this client will be created on a 
        // different computer when I do readl udp punch holing
        UdpClient newClient = ConstructUdpClient(info);

        // send data
        newClient.Send(dataToSend, dataToSend.Length);
    }

    // Construct a socket with the info received from the client
    static UdpClient ConstructUdpClient(IPEndPoint clientInfo)
    {
        var ip = clientInfo.Address.ToString();
        var port = clientInfo.Port;

        // this is the part I was missing!!!!
        // the local end point must match. this should be the ip this computer is listening on
        // and also the port            
        UdpClient client = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000));

        // lastly we are missing to set the end points. (ip and port client is listening on)

        // the connect method sets the remote endpoints
        client.Connect(ip, port);

        return client;
    }
}
```

I also have opened a port in my router so when data is received from my router's gateway address, it will map to my hosting computer on 192.168.1.101:1000 as shown here:

[image: NAT Virtual Server setting]

I also have the following client defined, which is running on another machine (192.168.1.108) on the LAN:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace UDPClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ipOfServer = "205.172.111.250";
            int portServerIsListeningOn = 11000;

        // send data to server
        Socket sending_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPAddress send_to_address = IPAddress.Parse(ipOfServer);
        IPEndPoint sending_end_point = new IPEndPoint(send_to_address, portServerIsListeningOn);
        sending_socket.SendTo(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test"), sending_end_point);

        // get info
        var port = sending_socket.LocalEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[1];

        // now wait for server to send data back
        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(port));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        sending_socket.Receive(buffer); // <----- we can receive data now!!!!!
    }
}
```

}

Please notice the ipOfServer.  This is my external gateway (not really since I obfuscated it, but it is not 192.168.1.101 - the internal IP of my UDP server).

When I direct the client to send to the internal LAN IP of 192.168.1.101:11000, the UDP Server connects.

However, when I use the gateway's IP address and port, the UDP Server does not connect.  Since I have the port directed to 192.168.1.101:1000 in the NAT, I'm not sure what gives.

I know the NAT setting are good since I also have port 80 for HTTP and port 808 for net.tcp all working from anywhere, even outside of my network.

Please give me some insight as to what I am doing wrong.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what's wrong without having access to your actual network setup. However, the scheme of creating a socket just to receive some data which is discarded, only to then create a new socket which you then "connect" to the client, seems wrong. You probably shouldn't be using `Connect()` with a UDP socket in the first place, and if you feel you must, you should just connect the original socket, once you have received some data.

In any case, it's really the client side of things that you need to worry about. You have already set up the router to forward datagrams inbound for the server, so the server should always be able to receive on that port. It's the return traffic to the client that is in question; the fact is, not all routers support this scenario, and always require port forwarding for UDP traffic (TCP traffic is easier because there is an on-going connection the router can maintain with the client).

I recommend that you make the server simpler – just create a single socket used to receive datagrams (and so of course don't dispose it with `using`). I'd also advise not using `Connect()` as all that will do is unnecessarily restrict the server. I.e. it will prevent the server's socket from being able to handle more than one client. If you really want to do some per-client filtering, a better mechanism is for the server to always receive all datagrams, and then check the receive-from address itself to decide how to deal with the datagram.

Comment: I am really trying to implement UDP Hole Punching as described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching

I have tried deriving from Socket and calling Bind with the local IP (192.xxx) and still no connection from the outside world.

Comment: I have tried:
this.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.108"), 11000));

Calling bind on the gateway IP address throws an exception:
The requested address is not valid in its context

Comment: @NickV: there's nothing in your scenario that suggests you need to implement "hole punching". That technique is normally used _in lieu of_ configuring port forwarding in a router or proxy. It generally involves each client contacting a common, third server, taking advantage of a _sometimes_ implemented behavior in NAT routers wherein once that third server replies to a client, the other client can also send to the first client and have the router forward traffic from it as well. There is no guarantee of this working for any given router, and isn't needed when you forward the port explicitly.

Comment: @NickV: (continued...) you definitely cannot bind to the gateway's address. The only legal addresses to bind are those hosted by the local machine. Normally, you just bind to IPAddress.Any, so that the socket can receive datagrams sent to any IP address hosted by that machine.

Comment: Thank you, Peter, for your comments. However, this server is simply part of a larger system that will incorporate P2P sound and video. I already have the P2P UDP portions to send sound and video. I need to now incorporate a hole punching method to get the P2P system working.

I have contemplated WCF P2P as well as a centralized forwarding method. I will have load balancing limited to no more than 10 peers on any given computer, so forwarding sound and video packets should not be a big deal, but latency is a concern.

P2P first needs a UDP server in which the NAT's ext. IP is sent to each node.

Comment: Peter, you actually helped me more than I expected and I thank you very much for it!

The trick was binding to IPAddress.Any!